# I'm trying to enable disk mirroring on a Thermaltake blacX duet, but it won't recognize the mirroring

Tags: windows, raid

My Product owner recently purchased a 2 drive externa docking station, and I'm trying to do mirroring dual backup over 1 USB, and was wondering if I can do mirroring with http://www.thermaltake.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00001756 and how I can do it.